# Can I transit via Schengen with visa-free days expired?

Tags: schengen, layovers, long-stay-visas, permits

I have read some (or all) related questions and answers on this site, but I still have doubts whether or not I understand the situation precisely.

My situation:

- Non-EU citizen, but a visa-free citizen for Schengen.
- Before getting a residence permit in Sweden, I used up all my Schengen visa-free days.
- My residence permit by Sweden expires on the same day on which my residence permit by France begins. Which happens on the day just before the day on which my visa-free Schengen period renews.

Does this mean that:

- I have to travel directly from Sweden to France and precisely on the day on which my French permit begins? I.e., I cannot legally layover in another Schengen country?

**Update:**
Oops, I have just noticed that my Swedish residence permit is for 92 days (3 months), while the Schengen area calculates based on days, not months. This means that my Schengen area passport time renews two days before I have to leave Sweden. This in turn means that I will be legally able to do layovers in Schengen starting 2 days before the deadline to leave Sweden :)

Comment: If there us no gap between the 2 permits, there is no problem. If you have been in Sweden, with the residence permit, for more that 180 days: then your day count is 0.

Comment: @MarkJohnson My visa-free Schengen period lapses exactly on the day which follows the date of expiry of my Swedish permit. Until then, I'm not permitted to go outside of Sweden or, then, outside of France.

Comment: With 'visa-free Schengen period' do you mean the 90/180 days rule? How many days have you been outside of Sweden in the **last** 180 days?

Comment: How long have you been in Sweden under your residence permit? Did Sweden grant you a super-short residence permit?

Comment: @sequence That's not exatly how the 90/180 rule works but it would be easier if you simply gave us some idea of where you have been in the past 6 months or so.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Isn't that already clear from the question?

Comment: @Relaxed More useful would be when the Swedish permit started and how many days has the OP been outside of Sweden in the last 180 days.

Comment: @Relaxed Sweden granted me a 3-month residence permit. On the date which follows the date of my Swedish residence permit expiry, I will have spent 180 days in the Schengen area, of which I have already spent 90 out of 90 days in the Schengen area on my visa-free passport.

Comment: Then, legally, a layover in another Schengen country is not possible and you must travel precisely on the day both permits are valid directly from Sweden to France.

Comment: @sequence You spent exactly 90 days in Sweden? On the 90th day you're stuck but on the91st, you can spend another 90 days elsewhere. That's counterintuitive to many people but you can use the Commission's calculator to double-check. One way to look at this is that on the 91st day, the last 180 days include 89 days in the Schengen area visa-free, 90 days in Sweden, and the current day whose status you're trying to determine. The 180-day window doesn't reach all the way to your original day of entry.

Comment: @Relaxed As far as I understand my Swedish residence permit starts on the day immediately following the 90th day of my stay in the Schengen area. My visa-free stay in the Schengen area renews exactly on the day following the day my Swedish residence permit expires. However, along with my residence permit, I also received a letter saying that I have to leave Sweden on or before the expiry date of my residence permit. So, even though my Schengen area stay would renew, I still have to leave Sweden before this happens.

Comment: It seems I can also leave Sweden on the last day of my residence permit, if I want to do some layovers, but in such a way as to be in any layover Schengen country no sooner than the day following the date of expiry of my Swedish residence permit.

Comment: Oops, I have just noticed that my Swedish residence permit is for 92 days (3 months), while the Schengen area calculates based on days, not months. This means that my Schengen area passport time renews two days before I have to leave Sweden. This in turn means that I will be legally able to do layovers in Schengen starting 2 days before the deadline to leave Sweden :)

Comment: @sequence There is no such thing as a visa-free stay period "renewing", that's why I phrased the question differently. There is also a distinction between 3 months and 90 days. So forget all the reasoning and count the days. Note that in practice I don't think any of this matters a lot.

Comment: @Relaxed Can you please clarify about the renewal thing?

Comment: @sequence On any given day, you have to consider the 180-day window ending on that day. The Schengen Borders Code was amended to counteract some court case based on this notion of a 180-day period renewing at some point. It may or may not make a difference in your case but it's not a good way to think about all this. Instead, just count the days using the calculator.

Comment: @Relaxed If I apply the 180-day window to 2 days before my Swedish residence permit expires, it is exactly 180 days since the entry to the Schengen area.

Comment: In your particular case, for this time, it does not matter since the counted days increase as fast as the days get discounted. But it's better to think about the rolling 180-day window than a notion of "renewal", in case you need to calculate the days later for other purposes or for another situation.

Comment: @xngtng The only thing, however, is that it is not precisely known whether or not I would need to leave the Schengen area before I can legally apply the 180-day window, so maybe it's still safer to leave Sweden no sooner than my French permit activates.